# Checking URL fragment for a keyword

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, url, fragment

i use the following to take a URL e.g. domain.com/#2 and then i use that fragment to redirect the users to domain.com/?page=2.

However, sometimes the user may be shown just a single hash and no number or i might use a keyword in the URL when clicking a form e.g. /#feedback.

The problem is this causes an issue with the code i use. How can i modify the provided code in a way that will only act upon the URL if its how i want the URL to be.

One way is to check if the fragment value is 'feedback' for example, but i would like to catch a way for a user perhaps entering a value or an odd form just creating a blank fragment value.

If the URL doesnt contain a #(then a number) or a given page id then dont do anything.

So the URL of:

```
domain.com/#2
```

Will redirect to:

```
domain.com/?page=2
```

Or if the URL already has a ?page=(number) it will add the fragment value to the number so:

```
domain.com/?page=2#2
```

Will direct to:

```
domain.com/?page=4
```

My initial thought it checking if the fragment is numeric, otherwise treat it as a 0.

So this:

```
/* 
Check if the URL has a # value. When a user visits a page from another / reloads the page and
it has a # fragment included, this code converts the # value and redirects the user to a page
such as domain.php?page=THE FRAGMENT VALUE
If the URL already contains a page value, it adds that value to the hash value and will
redirect the user to the new value page.
*/

// First get the page URL and split it via # and ? signs
var parts = location.href.split('#');
var queryParameters = location.search.split('?');

// Now we get the value of the page value in the URL if there is one
var pageNumber = 0;
for(var i = 0; i < queryParameters.length; i++)
{
  var keyvaluePair = queryParameters[i].split('=');
  if(keyvaluePair[0] == 'page')
  {
    pageNumber = keyvaluePair[1];
    break;
  }
}

// Next we check how many parts there are in the URL and if this a value, we add it to the current page
// and redirect to that new page number
if(parts.length > 1)
{
  var params = parts[0].split('?');
  var mark = '?';
  if(params.length > 1)
{
mark = '?';
}
var newPageNumber = parseInt(parts[1], 10) + parseInt(pageNumber, 10);
location.href = mark + 'page=' + newPageNumber;
}
```

Comment: Can you give expected/sample 'input' and 'output'?

Comment: Have you tried `location.hash` instead of splitting on `location.href`?

Comment: Just updated the question with some examples of what i want to happen / what happens currently to URLs

Answer (score 0):

First set a global variable for the page number; then check if the "page" query string variable is set and is numeric ([source](https://stackoverflow.com/a/901144/3141031)).

```
var pageNum = 0;

function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

if(!isNaN(getParameterByName('page'))) pageNum += parseInt(getParameterByName('page'));
```

Then check `window.location.hash` for the hash. If it is numeric, add it to `pageNum`. Else check if it is a command.

```
    if(!isNaN(parseInt(window.location.hash.replace(/#/, '')))) {
    pageNum += parseInt(window.location.hash.replace(/#/, ''));
} else if(window.location.hash != null) {
    switch(window.location.hash) {
        case "feedback":
            window.location.href = 'domain.com/feedback';
            break;
        default: 
            // do nothing?
            break;
    }
}
```

Finally, redirect the user if `pageNum > 0`.

```
if(pageNum > 0) window.location.href = 'domain.com/?page=' + pageNum;
```

Complete code:

```
var pageNum = 0;

function getParameterByName(name) {
    name = name.replace(/[\[]/, "\\[").replace(/[\]]/, "\\]");
    var regex = new RegExp("[\\?&]" + name + "=([^&#]*)"),
        results = regex.exec(location.search);
    return results == null ? "" : decodeURIComponent(results[1].replace(/\+/g, " "));
}

if(!isNaN(getParameterByName('page'))) pageNum += parseInt(getParameterByName('page'));

if(!isNaN(parseInt(window.location.hash.replace(/#/, '')))) {
    pageNum += parseInt(window.location.hash.replace(/#/, ''));
} else if(window.location.hash != null) {
    switch(window.location.hash) {
        case "feedback":
            window.location.href = 'domain.com/feedback';
            break;
        default: 
            // do nothing?
            break;
    }
}

if(pageNum > 0) window.location.href = 'domain.com/?page=' + pageNum;
```

Comment: Thanks for the time writing this, looks great! Wont be able to test until sunday but i shall let you know. Craig.