# Manipulate menu links when started "example.com/#link1"

Tags: javascript, jquery

Would like to know how to handle when the page is loaded in one of menu links.

```
<ul>
 <li><a href="#link1"></a></li>
 <li><a href="#link2"></a></li>
 <li><a href="#link3"></a></li>
</ul>
```

when the URL starts with #link1 or #link2 or #link3, manipulate:

```
if('example.com/#link1') {
 alert('link1');
} else if ('example.com/#link2') {
 alert('link2');
} else if ('example.com/#link3') {
 alert('link3');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It sounds like you need to check the URL fragment in  JavaScript. Related answers:

- [Parsing URL hash/fragment identifier with JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4197591/parsing-url-hash-fragment-identifier-with-javascript)
- [Checking URL fragment for a keyword](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24366549/checking-url-fragment-for-a-keyword)

Example (using [window.location.hash](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window.location) )

```
if (window.location.hash === "link1") {
 alert('link1');
} else if (window.location.hash === "link2") {
 alert('link2');
} else if (window.location.hash === "link3") {
 alert('link3');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to detect hash (#) in the current page url, you should check `window.location.hash`. It will returns string like `#link1` if you are on site.com/#link1 page